# Jquery DataTable issue , json response not filling table

Tags: jquery, datatables

If I just use a local `data:data` source it works, but when I use ajax no data will fill the table...Any ideas?

```
//var myObj ={"data": { "id":"John", "created_at":31 }};
///var data = [myObj];
$table = $('#client_search').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    info: false,
    processing: true,
   // serverSide: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
            extend: 'colvis',
            text: 'Show/Hide Columns'
        },
        'pageLength',
        'print',
        'excelHtml5',

    ],
    //data:data['data'],
    ajax: {
        url: '/admin/reports/client-search',
        type: 'post',
        dataSrc:'data',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
    },
    columns: [
        {data:"id"},
        {data:"created_at"},
    ]
   
});
```

///response from server

```
{"data":{"id":3,"created_at":"2021-07-30T18:30:36.000000Z"}}
```

```
    <table class="table table-striped display responsive nowrap datatable" id="client_search">
        <thead >
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">id</th>
                <th scope="col">created at</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That JSON response is valid JSON, but is not valid for DataTables. DataTables needs the JSON to contain an array `[ ... ]` - where each element in the array represents one row of table data. So, for example, the following would work for a single row: `{ "data": [ {"id": 3, "created_at": "2021-07-30T18:30:36.000000Z"} ] }`. Or for multiple table rows: `{ "data": [ { ... }, { ... }, ... ] }`. But you need the array. Without that, DataTables has nothing to iterate over, to build the table rows for you.

Comment: And I see you do that for your local JavaScript data: `var data = [myObj];`. You put the `myObj` data into an array!

Comment: @andrewJames, gonna try this out. Weird the docs shows examples of objects not in arrays. And this is me working 190+ hours in the past two weeks lol. Thanks

Comment: I have never seen an example which does not use an array. Can you share one? Get some sleep!